# JDBC Driver isn't loading properly in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, beanshell

Whenever I run the following code:

```
public void insertIntoMysql() {

    URLClassLoader childCl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL("file:///myProjectDir/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar")}, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

    try {
        // connect to mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", true, childCl);
        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "adminpw");

        ...
    } catch {
        ...
    }
}
```

I get a "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB" error when the DriverManager is called.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that I loaded my driver with a custom classloader (I'm unable to modify the calling code, so can't change the classpath that is loaded when my script is called). It seems to find the driver just fine in the Class.forName line, but it's like that class was never loaded just two lines later.

Any thoughts?

--- UPDATE ---

I figured out how to add a jar to my classpath at runtime using a BeanShell util, removed the outdated forName, and stopped using a custom classloader. My updated code is below:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

public void insertIntoMysql() {

    try {
        addClassPath("/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar");
        // printing out the classpath URLs here shows several
        // jar files along with the one I just added:
        // file:/C:/myProjectDir/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

        // connect to mysql
        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "adminpw");

        ...
    } catch {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I still get the same SQLException that I was originally getting even though my class path has been updated.

I also tried calling BeanShell's "reloadClasses()" method right after adding the new classpath, to no avail.

Comment: Is "/myProjectDir/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" the absolute path to the jar?

Comment: Yup it is. I know that's poor form, but I'm going to worry about cleaning it up when I get this working.

Comment: Why do you need to use the custom classloader? Can you remove that line and just call Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")?

Comment: @exxodus7 The only way you will get it working is by cleaning it up.

Comment: @BarbiePylon I need it because the jar containing the driver isn't loaded by the main classloader, so the forName line throws a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @EJP What do you mean by "clean it up"?

Comment: @exxodus7 I mean exactly the same as you mean by 'cleaning it up'.  You're the one who introduced the term. The fact is that you're going to have to add the JAR file to the CLASSPATH of the application, which does not require changing the code that calls this method, and you can then remove the `Class.forName()` call, which hasn't been needed since 2007.

Comment: @EJP Right, I did say that. I understand that I can't use a custom ClassLoader. I'm just trying to figure out how, then, to do this with the main classloader and I guess I just don't understand classloaders well enough (so bear with me). How do I change the classpath in the way you're saying? I assumed the calling program was running something like "java <classpath params> myjavascript", and so assumed I couldn't change the default classpath as it was set within the calling application.

Comment: Well you're just going to have to to find out, aren't you? We can't tell you how your own software is executed.

Comment: Please note that Java code is not 'script', and it is not Javascript either.

Comment: Ok so to sum up: I don't know how my software is being called. I assume I can't change the classpath being loaded when it is called because the calling code is out of my reach. Given that, it seems that what I want to do is impossible. Sorry about the "script" confusion, its technically BeanShell (java scripting language). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can see no reason whatsoever to just blindly assume that you can't change the CLASSPATH. That's not a property of code, it's a property of a script or an environment or a build procedure or a JAR manifest file or ... Don't just guess. Investigate. In any case changing the CLASSPATH is the solution. The only solution. You're just going to have to find out how to do that.

Comment: @EJP Investigated setting the classpath, please see update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this has to do with the custom classloader used to load the class. This is also mentioned in the Javadocs of [`DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> When the method `getConnection` is called, the `DriverManager` will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the **same classloader** as the current applet or application.

Comment: Huh, so as I'm unable to change the calling code (and therefore, I guess, the main classloader) then DriverManager will never work? This explains to me why my code doesn't work (thank you!) but is there a solution?

Comment: @exxodus7 Could you explain more about how you're running this in your question? Why do you need to use the custom classloader?

Comment: @exxodus7 You have to change the calling code. It doesn't work. It has never worked. It will never work. It's worthless.

Comment: @manouti I'm executing this within a script that is called by software that I don't have any access to and so cannot change how my script is called.

Comment: @manouti If i remove the use of my custom classloader, the driver's jar file is never loaded and the forName line throws a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @EJP Gotcha, removed the line. Unfortunately I still have the same exception when the DriverManager is called since the Driver isn't loaded from the main classpath.

Comment: @manouti You don't need `Class.forName()` here anyway, with or without `jdbc.drivers.` It became obsolete with JDBC 4 in 2007.

Comment: @exxodus7 You don't seem to be listening. You can't use a custom ClassLoader. Read the quote in the answer above.

Answer (score -1):

The jar file should be in your **classpath**